# i m new to angular 2 i have installed node v5 and npm v3 while trying npm install following error

Tags: angular

E:\AngularDemo\angular2-quickstart>npm install
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\
node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6

npm ERR! No compatible version found: @angular/router-deprecated@2.0.0-rc.3
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["2.0.0-rc.2","2.0.0-rc.1","2.0.0-rc.0","0.0.0-7","0.0.0-6"]
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\AngularDemo\angular2-quickstart\npm-debug.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Package.json and change

from

```
"@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
```

to

```
"@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
```

Or copy entire package.json from - 
https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: thanks it works for me but still other problem still exist

Comment: if its works then mark as answer and for other problem you can raise another question.